# Convert String to html in label AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an angular snippet in which I want to convert string to HTML object.

```
 `<div class="row">
     <label class="col-md-4 info_text">Remarks<span>:</span></label> <label
      class="col-md-8 fieldValue">{{initialTableInfo.comments}}
     </label>
    </div>`
```

The `initialTableInfo.comments` has the value `<b>someText</b>`. It is getting printed as it is. I want "someText" to be printed as **someText** instead of `<b>someText</b>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can render string to html using `$sce.trustAsHtml(html)` and use  **`ng-bind-html.`**

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.initialTableInfo ={};
$scope.initialTableInfo.comments =  '<b>someText</b>';
})

.filter('trustHtml',function($sce){
  return function(html){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <div class="background-white p20 reasons"  >
    <h6><b>About {{aboutlongs[0].name}}</b></h6>
    <div class="reason-content" ng-bind-html="$scope.initialTableInfo.comments | trustHtml" >
     
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the $sce parameter for angular.

```
module.controller('myctrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$sce',function($scope, $http, $sce) {

$scope.initialTableInfo.comments = $sce.trustAsHtml("<b>Some Text<b>");

}]);
```

And in your HTML use **ng-bind-html**

```
<label class="col-md-8 fieldValue" ng-bind-html="initialTableInfo.comment"> </label>
```

Comment: Thank you alexi-coard - you have made my day!

Answer (score 1):

You should check this link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml.

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
</div>
```

As Alexi mentioned, be sure to have the correct syntax on the controller too.